# How do I take an output variable out of an analytics.js call in order to redirect?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, cross-domain, server-side

At my job we're trying to use google analytics to do some cross-domain tracking. The problem is that there's a server-side redirect involved. Our solution is to append the google analytics info to the initial URL.

We have a cart page with a checkout button. Clicking the checkout button triggers btnCheckout_OnClick, which creates a URL and then uses RegisterClientScriptBlock to access a javascript function on the page. That RegisterClientScriptBlock call looks like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "gaCrossDomain", "gaCrossDomain('" + checkoutUrl + "');", true);
```

Meanwhile, the Javascript so far looks like this:

```
function gaCrossDomain(url) {
    ga(function(tracker) {
        var linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
        var output = linker.decorate(url);
    });

}
```

the ga function call is a call to analytics.js. How it works is detailed here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#decorate

However, it's not detailed enough. To get to the bottom line of this question: how do I get "output" out of the ga function call? Once I have the modified url, I can use it for a redirect. Alternatively, is there any way I can redirect inside the ga call?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `output` in your wrapper function and then return it:

```
function gaCrossDomain(url) {
    var output;
    ga(function(tracker) {
        var linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
        output = linker.decorate(url);
    });
    return output;
}
```

**Example:**

```
var src = gaCrossDomain('http://www.somesite.com');
console.log(src); 
// output: http://www.somesite.com?_ga=1.181772207.989393484.1440257672"
```

**Note:** The value returned is only valid for 2 minutes, so this is not something you can really do early on and save for later use.

Comment: So ideally, instead of returning output, I'd just redirect. I tested this idea with a document.write(output), but that didn't put out anything. That shouldn't be the case, should it?

Comment: @user1038370 not sure why it didn't work for you.. is your UA instance namespaced?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this solution works. There's a problem because ga is an asynchronously-loaded external script

Comment: This is the code to get the value when the ga lib is loaded, yes.  So it sounds like you are attempting to call it during page load, and there's a race condition between it and the ga library. As I mentioned in my note, the code returned is only valid for 2 minutes. So, if you are attempting to add the code during page load, you run the risk of the code becoming invalid when the visitor clicks on a link later, if they click on a link 2m+ after the code is added.  So ideally, you should generate the code and append onclick of a link.

Comment: That is what we're doing though. "Clicking the checkout button triggers btnCheckout_OnClick, which creates a URL and then uses RegisterClientScriptBlock to access a javascript function on the page." But we can't get "output" out of the ga code, unless we put it in an alert or something (which I suspects only works because the alert executes after everything else or something).

Comment: i don't see how that is possible...unless you are also loading the ga library itself onclick?

Comment: Analytics code is loaded right after the opening body tag. gaCrossDomain() comes immediately after that, but it doesn't do anything until onclick

Comment: Also, since the javascript is being called with registerclientscriptblock from the codebehind, I can't do exactly what you're doing in your example